# implementation of vector maps

Tags: c++, oop, dictionary, vector, polymorphism

I need help getting started with this assignment. I have a base class `Shape`, and derived classes `MyCircle`, `MyRect`, and `MyTriangle`. 
For the assignment I need to generate the shapes randomly and store them into a map. 
Here is what I don't understand. It states: the key value in the map will be the shape type, and the mapped value will be a vector of Shape pointers.

I created the vector of Shape pointers as follows:

```
// define our array size
const int baseSize = 3;

// create an vector of base class pointers
vector <Shape *> baseShape(baseSize);


// declare our objects, and pointers for downcasting
MyRect rObj, *rPtr;
MyTriangle tObj, *tPtr;
MyCircle cObj, *cPtr;


// initialize our vector of base class pointers
//initialize vector of shapes
baseShape[0] = &rObj; // a MyRect IS A Shape
baseShape[1] = &tObj;   // a MyTriangle IS A Shape
baseShape[2] = &cObj; // a MyCircle IS A Shape
```

But I am not sure how to implement the map, more specifically, I don't understand why the key value type is a `Shape`. 
If I declared a map as follows

```
//map
map <Shape, vector <Shape *> > shapeMap;
```

Can the map do this?

```
shapeMap[rObj] = baseShape[0];
shapeMap[rObj] = baseShape[0];
shapeMap[rObj] = baseShape[0];
shapeMap[rObj] = baseShape[0];
```

...
20 times for each shape with the shape with different attributes.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

My interpretation would be that for the shape type you could create an enum of the types, and use that as the key.

```
enum class ShapeType { circle, square, triangle };

map<ShapeType, vector<Shape*>> shapes;
shapes[ShapeType::circle].push_back( new MyCircle{} );
```

(The couple of lines of code above don't delete the circle, unless that is done, there will be a memory leak.)

Comment: Better than the `enum` might be something along the lines of a `static const int ShapeType = <some value>` in each concrete class. They could even draw their values from an `enum`, I guess (e.g. `static const Shape::Type ShapeType = <some enum Shape::Type value>`)... But making the type identifier part of the class instead of a separate collection of data seems cleaner to me...

Answer (score 1):

> the key value in the map will be the shape type

Although I'm not 100% certain on the requirements, I take this to mean you should implement an enum like this:

```
enum ShapeType {
    Circle,
    Rectangle,
    Triangle
};
```

and declare your map like this:

```
map<ShapeType, vector <Shape *> > shapeMap;
```

Comment: `enum class`s are preferable unless compatibility with C++98 is required.